# Using symbolic links and git to manage build versions

Tags: linux, package-management, symlink, libraries, man

In general I follow the following workflow when I build any program (e.g. `emacs`, `tmux`, etc.)

```
/home/opt/[name of the program]/builds/[version]/

bin
lib
share
```

For example for a program like `tmux` I have the following:

```
/my_local_opt/tmux/builds/1.7.-227/

bin
lib
share
```

I then create sym links in `/home/bin/` pointing to the the specific builds that I have, and I never have to touch my `PATH` variable, since I fix it to include `/home/bin`.

E.g. For the example above, I would

- Create a sym link: from:  `/home/bin/tmux` to: `/my_local_opt/tmux/builds/1.7.-227/bin/tmux`
- Have `PATH` only include `/home/bin`

However, I am not sure I can follow a similar approach for the `man` (`MANPATH`) and `lib` (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) paths.

1. For example, after I build `tmux` I notice that it creates:

   > `.. /share/man/man1/tmux.1`

   so I tried creating a symlink to this file from a place like `/home/share` and then fixing `MANPATH` to include this path. But when I typed `man tmux` it didn't work (it said "`No manual entry for tmux`"). Why?
2. How about `lib`? I thought I could perhaps fix `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a specific directory for each program, and then use sym links to control which version gets included. Would this be a good idea?

More generally, is it a good idea to manage versions in a system using sym links? In the long run I am hoping to leave the sym links in a git repository to keep track of multiple configurations.

I don't have admin privileges in the machine where I build software, so I am hoping to use this as a way easily organize and manage my builds (without having to constantly edit my environment variables holding paths)

Comment: Your are manually doing what [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) does for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective is very similar to the [Gentoo Prefix](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix) system; it however doesn't keep the built applications seperately, nor store the symlinks in Git.

It will however fix your manpage and library needs (with the caveat that either `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set, or the configure & binaries have a specific path hard-coded).

Seperately, the git-of-symlinks model in itself is similar in concept to OverlayFS/AUFS model, with more mix & match in place.